# How can I add $term->slug and $term->name to an array as a key and value pair?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress module for the Beaver Builder plugin that will pull specific posts based on their custom taxonomy.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to pull a list of terms from my custom taxonomy to and properly put them in an array.

The module setup looks like this:

```
FLBuilder::register_module('MarketReportsModule', array(
    'general'       => array( // Tab
        'title'         => __('General', 'fl-builder'), // Tab title
        'sections'      => array( // Tab Sections
            'general'       => array( // Section
                'title'         => '', // Section Title
                'fields'        => array( // Section Fields
                    'reportcategory' => array(
                        'type'           => 'select',
                        'label'          => __( 'Report Category', 'fl-builder' ),
                        'options'        => $categories,
                    ),                  
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

And I am trying to populate the 'options' array with an array of my custom categories.

Normally, the options array would be input like this:

```
array(
    'key1' =>  __( 'value1', 'fl-builder' ),
    'key2' =>  __( 'value2', 'fl-builder' ),
    'key3' =>  __( 'value3', 'fl-builder' ),
),
```

I am trying to input my categories using the following code, but it isn't working:

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'report_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
    $term_name = $term->name;
    $categories[$term_slug] = $term_name;
}
```

For each of my terms, I want to add the slug as a key and the name as a value. I do not have much experience with PHP so I'm sure I'm doing something totally wrong, but I have no idea what.

UPDATE: Apparently I cannot use the wordpress function get_terms() from within this plugin's modules. I was not able to find another way to call my custom taxonomy, so I had to give up on this route.

Comment: What does $categories print. print_r($categories);

Comment: @RavinderReddy It is printing out a blank array... 
`Array ( [] => ) Array ( [] => )`

Comment: ok. did you check $terms before foreach loop print_r($terms );

Comment: @RavinderReddy I did not, thank you. That was also coming up blank.

I am narrowing in on the issue. I am apparently not able to use get_terms() from within the module backend. I believe there are some theme-specific calls that I can do instead:

`$categories = FLBuilderLoop::taxonomies($slug);` 

I am now able to print out a list of taxonomies, so I think I'm at least getting close.